# Combiing two python lists into a cartesian product

Tags: python

I have two lists in python that have unique values in them like so:

```
# Sepearate lists
first_list = ["Hello", "World"]
second_list = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

I want the first_list to actually become a cartesian product of the two separate lists:

```
# So first_list should be
first_list = ["A:Hello", "B:Hello", "C:Hello", "A:World", "B:World", "C:World"]
```

I know I can do it like this (psuedo-code) but there should be a faster more precise way I think:

```
#Temp list
temp_list = []

for s in second_list: 
    for f in first_list:
        # The append expression is more C# than python and need that fixed
        temp_list.append(s + ":" f)

first_list = temp_list
```

The psuedo code is what I want but is there a better way?

Comment: You could use list comprehension: `first_list = [s + ":" + f for s in second_list for f in first_list]` However it's hard to say that this is much "better".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is fine, but you can also use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). For example like so

```
import itertools
# Sepearate lists
first_list = ["Hello", "World"]
second_list = ["A", "B", "C"]

print([f'{b}:{a}' for a, b in itertools.product(first_list, second_list)])
```

It will print  the following

```
['A:Hello', 'B:Hello', 'C:Hello', 'A:World', 'B:World', 'C:World']
```